# Pelican internal link to anchor

Tags: markdown, pelican

I have `2017/09/01/postA.md` with header anchor `anchor1`. From post `2017/09/02/postB.md` I want to link to `anchor1` of `postA`.

In `postB` I put

```
 [Link to post 1 anchor 1](../01/post#anchor1)
```

however it renders the above to the link: `...2017/09/02/01/postA#anchor1` instead of  `...2017/09/01/postA#anchor1`.

How to link to anchor correctly?

Comment: http://docs.getpelican.com/en/3.6.3/content.html#linking-to-internal-content

Comment: Forget to put the `.md` thanks

Comment: For others finding this question, the anchors will not be generated by default. You need to enable the `toc` extension in markdown for this to work.
Check https://github.com/getpelican/pelican/issues/1357